# delete items from a list compared to another list while iterating python

Tags: python

I am trying to delete an item from a list in a for loop but as the first item gets removed the list goes out of range to be deleted from. I have tried a few different ways of getting around it, but none of them worked. Here is the original code:

```
availibleMoves = ["TL", "TM", "TR", "CL", "CM", "CR", "BL", "BM", "BR"]
while True:
    print("Please enter the current state of the board in 1D, current move is", move)
    current_board = input("> ")
    board_list = list(current_board)
    if len(board_list) != 9:
        print("Please enter the correct value\n\n")
    else:
        for i in range(0, 9):
            if board_list[i] == "0":
                pass
            else:
                del availibleMoves[i]
        print(availibleMoves)
        break
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks, sorry if this question is bad but I am in year 10 doing computer science GCSE and this is just a project for fun.

Edit: an example of what I typed in as an input was
`100000001`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It's hard to work out what's wrong when I don't know what `availableMoves` is, for example.

Comment: ```availableMoves``` is undefined. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added what availibleMoves is defined as

Comment: Dont delete from the list. Collect all indexes to be deleted in another list, then sort decending and delete that .... if you delete the biggest value , then the next biggest one your deletion wont impact the lists indexing. If you delete 1 first now 2 is at 1 and the whole list is 1 shorter. Probably better to change your whole code to something more sensible like using a list comp and zip() on your input to get open moves.

Comment: Rather than try to delete the element, how about setting it to None. Deleting in the way you're doing it now (depending on the input value) will almost inevitably lead to an IndexError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (horribly unpythonic) way of doing this would be to go through the list backwards:

```
for i in range(9 - 1, -1, -1):
    if board_list[i] != "0":
        del availibleMoves[i]
```

However, other suggestions here would be much better.

Answer (score 3):

For this usecase I think it would be easier to use a dictionary to store each board position and their values.

```
if len(current_board) != 9:
    print("Please enter the correct value\n\n")
    continue
board = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(current_board)}
```

For example, `"001002000"` becomes:

```
{0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '1', 3: '0', 4: '0', 5: '2', 6: '0', 7: '0', 8: '0'}
```

To get the available moves you can loop over the dictionary to find all of the positions that are value `'0'`

```
available_moves = [i for i, v in board.items() if v == '0']
```

Which returns

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

If you want to reference this by the string names instead of index values, you can `zip` the names with the input:

```
>>> current_board = "001002000"
>>> moves = ["TL", "TM", "TR", "CL", "CM", "CR", "BL", "BM", "BR"]

>>> board = {m: v for m, v in zip(moves, current_board)}
>>> board
{'TL': '0', 'TM': '0', 'TR': '1', 'CL': '0', 'CM': '0', 'CR': '2', 'BL': '0', 'BM': '0', 'BR': '0'}

>>> available_moves = [m for m, v in board.items() if v == '0']
>>> available_moves 
['TL', 'TM', 'CL', 'CM', 'BL', 'BM', 'BR']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to only keep the values that are `1` in your entered board rather than removing the ones with values `0`.

This is because every time you remove a value, all the indices after that value also shift back by 1.

```py
...
else:
    ret = [board_list[i] for i in range(9) if board_list[i] == '1']
    break
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that you're shrinking the size of the list by deleting items, but still trying to loop through 9 items. You could try substitute for some other value and then remove them if you really need. Something like this:

```
        for i in range(0,9):
            if board_list[i] != "0" and i < 9:
                availibleMoves[i] = -1
        while -1 in availibleMoves:
            availibleMoves.remove(-1)
```